# Laravel / Sanctum Authenticate without user / password

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, api, authentication

I have **website A** which is a simple HTML + JS website.
This website needs to communicate with **website B** which is quite simple REST API built on *laravel 10 and sanctum*

I want to create simple authentication to allow **website A** execute requests on **website B**.
I don't want to create any login / register form with user/password.

I thought about authorization with tokens, but it won't work because the token must be passed somehow and it will be visible in JS or the inspector.

Comment: You'll need some kind of server-side code (HTML and JS are executed on the client), in order for website A to communicate with website B.

Comment: Like PHP, for example

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but it only adds another layer (still without correct authentication), for example ill implement like `/ajax_get_data.php` on **website A** which will communicate with **website B** using hidden / secret token (php) - but still someone can inspect via F12 and then create manual requests to the `/ajax_get_data.php`

Comment: So what are the conditions you want to enforce that will allow/disallow website A to call website B?

Comment: This is the fundamental question I would like an answer to - how to authenticate **website A** in **website B** so that it is impossible to **spoof or steal data**.

Comment: Authenticating between website A and website B doesn't seem to be your problem - this can be done behind the scenes, server-side, with private messaging between the two websites that is not shared with the user.  In fact, the user may never know about the existence of website B.  Is it perhaps instead that you want to constrain what the user can or can't do in their interactions with website A?

Comment: If you don't want to use a user/pass combination, then you could look at other constraints - like IP range restriction, or a sequence of actions that must be performed on website A in the correct order, or some other constraint.  That is down to your business logic

Comment: Just to further clarify, you want **website A**, not **individual users on website**, right? Alice and Bob aren't "signing" into A, they're just viewing it and it is making an JavaScript call to **website B** to get some data. So when **website A** is scraped we can then get the data?